# Serilog log certain object attributes of a list of objects

Tags: c#, .net, serilog

Given a list of objects, I'd like to log a specific attribute of each element in the list (say, its name). The only thing I can think of is logging in a forloop. Is there a better way to achieve what I want?

Small example:

```
public class Dog
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public bool CanBark{ get; set; }
}
```

and then somewhere else in my code

```
public void GetAllDogsWithLogs(){
    List<Dog> barkingDogs = GetBarkingDogs();
    foreach(var dog in barkingDogs){  // ---> I'd like to avoid a forloop just for logging
        Log.Debug("Found barking dog {Name} with Id {Id}", dog.Name, dog.Id);
    }
}
```

Note that I cannot log all attributes of my objects, since that would introduce way too much noise into my logs.

Comment: You could create a dictionary containing the names and ID's, and log that instead. It depends on whether you want many log events or a single one. If you want many, then a loop is perfectly reasonable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For posterity: I ended up solving this using LINQ:

```
Log.Debug("Found barking dogs with name and ID {NameIds}", 
            barkingDogs.Select(dog => (dog.Name, dog.Id));
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend leveraging the destructuring mechanism in Serilog to support this.

You can use the special `@` character when logging the entity to trigger destructuring of the object as documented here:

- [Preserving Object Structure](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Structured-Data#preserving-object-structure)

```cs
Log.Debug("Found barking dog {@Dog}", dog);
```

Then, configure the destructuring logic as per here:

- [Customizing the stored data](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Structured-Data#customizing-the-stored-data)

```cs
new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Destructure.ByTransforming<Dog>(
        d => new { Name = d.Name, /* add other properties here */ })
```

This relies on inline configuration so it can get a bit verbose.

If you want a more general purpose destructuring logic, you could implement your own `IDestructuringPolicy` that checks for the presence of an attribute on each property for example, or just use one of the existing solutions from here:

- https://github.com/destructurama

This particular package allows you to control destructuring via attributes which would give you the general purpose solution right away without having to implement your own logic:

- https://github.com/destructurama/attributed

Just configure the logger like this:

```
var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
  .Destructure.UsingAttributes()
```

And then use the `[LogWithName]` and `[NotLogger]` attributes accordingly to customize the name / opt-out of the log data for a particular object:

```cs
public class Dog
{
    [LogWithName("DogNameOrSomething")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [NotLogged]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [NotLogged]
    public bool CanBark{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the verbose answer! I saw these solutions as well. What I dislike about them is that I either would need to configure the destructuring logic of ALL elements in a centralized location, which doesn't sound very clean. Using `destructurama` on the other hand does not give me the flexibility to log different things in different places AFAIU.